# spring data jdbc BeforeConvertCallback is not working anymore from 3.0.6 onwards

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

In spring data jdbc bundled with spring boot 3.0.5 I could generate an Id by using the BeforeConvertCallback:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories
class JdbcConfig extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {

    @Bean
    BeforeConvertCallback<MyEntity> beforeSaveCallback() {
        return (entity) -> {
            if (entity.getId() == null) {
                entity.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            }
            return entity;
        };
    }
```

With 3.0.6 I get now an SQL error ('ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation'), that the Id is missing, therefore I assume that the BeforeConvertCallback is not longer called.

I went through all versions >= 3.0.6 and none of them have the behaviour I expect.

Comment: That sounds like a regression. Could you please create a ticket on Github, with a reproducer?

Comment: Yes, I will do.

Comment: The repo to reproduce is here: https://github.com/hubertvolz/becoca.

Comment: And now a github issue is also created: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/1532. @JensSchauder: if something is missing or unclear, don't hesitate to ask me. I don't have experience in creating meaningful github issues and proper code to reproduce problems.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Paluch commented on the related [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2853) the problem is a regression that causes lambdas not to get picked up as callbacks.

He recommends the following workarounds

> Please avoid lambdas

or

> Another workaround is moving the lambda callbacks into a non-@Configuration class that you import via @Import(…).

Comment: With spring boot 3.1.1 it works now like expected. Thanks a lot!